# Bullying - булінг чи цькування?

Tags: значення-слів, запозичені-слова

Зараз багато говорять на тему агресивної поведінки, власне, у школі та в мережі інтернет. При цьому стали казати **булінг**, і наче це надає якоїсь нової ваги проблемі, яка була завжди. Ніби це нове явище. Я ще погоджувалася, коли **булінгом** називали поведінку знущання в месенджерах і на сайтах, це нове явище, хай буде англицизм, щоб виділяти його зпоміж сімейного, колективного та армійського знущання. Але тепер говорять багато про школу, і знову **булінг**. Хіба нема на це слова **цькування**?

[Bullying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullying) is the use of force, threat, or coercion to abuse, intimidate or aggressively dominate others.

[Цькування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), булінг (англ. bully — залякувати, цькувати, задирати) — прояв агресії з подальшим залякуванням особистості і появою можливості її повного підпорядкування собі і своїм інтересам.

[ЦЬКУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cjkuvaty) 2. перен., розм. Переслідувати кого-небудь різними нападками, наклепами і т. ін., знущатися з когось.

Хто знає причину, за якою варто вживати англицизм, називаючи згадану поведінку? Чи є в слова **булінг** такі додаткові відтінки значення, які справді відрізняють його від українського слова **цькування**?

Сама ж я схильна думати, що вжиток англійського слова має причиною любов аудиторії до нових цікавих іноземних слів.

Я не зовсім проти, якщо аудиторія клює на слово **булінг** і таким чином можна справді звернути увагу суспільства на проблему. Та цікаво, чи є лінгвістичне підґрунтя такого запозичення?

Answer (score 4):

Можливо, ви маєте рацію, що українці доволі-таки часто надають перевагу англицизмам. Але це предмет вивчення іншої царини.

Для використання слова булінг все-таки є підстави. В українській мові довгий час "цькувати" мало основне значення "наганяти собак на когось". У значенні "знущання над кимось" воно з'явилось пізніше й випливало з основного значення.[[джерело]](http://sum.in.ua/s/cjkuvaty)

В той час як в англійській слово *bully* мало одне значення (те, в якому його зараз і вживають). Більш того, усі авторитетні тлумачні словники англійської мови такі, як [Оксфордський](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bully), [Кембриджський](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bully) та [Колінс](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bully) наводять приклади вживання цього слова саме у значенні шкільного або дитячого булінгу, що в принципі одне й те саме.

Це наводить на думки, що українці вживають слово *булінг* частіше, бо воно не має побічних значень. Хоча ваша версія також не позбавлена сенсу, бо можна знайти велику кількість статей про цькування, де англицизм використовується узаголовку, проте український відповідник - у самій статті.

Comment: Але "напускати собак" і "нападати на когось" - це схожі за рівнем аґресії речі, саме тому на їх позначення використовується одне й те саме слово. Не розумію, як перше значення заважає другому існувати, і як через перше значення друге значення менш синонімічне до "булін(г)/(ґ)".

Comment: По-перше, значення "нападати на когось" з'явилось від того, що ці речі схожі, ви праві. Але в українській мові основним значенням виступає все-таки "напускати собак", а в англійській мові "булінг" має єдине значення. Ці слова аж ніяк не заважають один одному в співіснуванні, і особисто я виступаю за використання українського відповідника.

Comment: Слова "хоча", "не", "позбавлена" мають досить неґативне забарвлення. Вирішив уточнити. Дякую, що прояснили свою позицію. Щодо "основного значення", то воно основне лише в словнику (який зараз перероблюється в оновлений, позбавлений комуністичних цитат "СУМ-20"), а "цькування" в сучасних медіа все-таки набагато частіше зустрічається саме у другому значенні.

Answer (score 3):

Ви праві, слово "булінг" і справді стало популярним. Правда, не розумію чому, бо в українській мові є багато слів, якими можна його замінити.

Перш за все - це цькування. Такий відповідник обрали на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bulinh), він є і в СУМі, і на Вікіпедії. Якщо ми говоримо про цькування в школі, то на Вікіпедії є стаття "[Шкільне цькування](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)".

Є в нашій мові і слово "[знущання](http://sum.in.ua/s/znushhannja)":

> 2. Зла насмішка, глузування.

[Знущатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/znushhatysja):

> 1. Заподіювати муки, страждання кому-небудь.
> 2. Зле висміювати кого-, що-небудь, глузувати з когось, чогось.

Мені здається, що "знущання" є хорошим відповідиком, бо воно може бути не лише фізичним, але й психологічним, так само як і "булінг".